# Turn on shell_exec only for some hosts

Tags: nginx, php, shell-exec

i using nginx and php-fpm as default webserver without apache.
So, for best security each host have own php-fpm pool.

I am have a problem with shell_exec again - i no want to turn on for all users, but i need use this function for some host (1 or 3 hosts, no more).

shell_exec is turned off in php.ini.
I try to enable shell_exec in site php-fpm pool, but it's not working:

```
php_admin_value[shell_exec] = on
```

Answer (score 3):

Something else to consider is to disable the `disable_function` in the primary `php.ini` file.

Then set the `disable_function` for each FPM Pool: (For example)

```
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

If you have a specific FPM Pool which you need to use one or more of those functions, just remove it from that pools configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a whitelist IP hosts as this :

```
$whitelist = array('127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1', 'whateverIPyouAuth');
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)){
    //shell_exec call here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `suhosin.executor.func.blacklist`

1)Comment `disable_function` in php.ini 
2)below add this line (List all functions to be blacklisted.Same as disable_function)

`suhosin.executor.func.blacklist = exec, passthru, shell_exec, system, proc_open, popen, apache_child_terminate, apache_setenv, define_syslog_variables,
pcntl_exec, openlog, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname,
proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_open, proc_terminate, syslog, curl_exec, curl_multi_exec, php_uname, phpinfo`

3)Within the virtual host section using the line:

```
php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist ".."
```

So you can redefine the black listed functions for that particular virtual host.

In your case all functions except `shell_exec`.

It will be `php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist "passthru, shell_exec, system, proc_open, popen, apache_child_terminate, apache_setenv, define_syslog_variables,
pcntl_exec, openlog, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname,
proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_open, proc_terminate, syslog, curl_exec, curl_multi_exec, php_uname, phpinfo"`

[Reference](http://blog.jak.me/2013/03/25/disabling-php-functions-on-a-per-virtual-host-basis/)